# How to handle click event in angular1 directive test cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write test case for my directive in anguarjs1.x

here is my directive

```
 .directive("weeklyDirective", function($timeout) {
        return {
            scope: {
                data: '=',
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                scope.weekDays = [
                    { text: 'Sun', id: 1 },
                    { text: 'Mon', id: 2 },
                    { text: 'Tue', id: 3 },
                    { text: 'Wed', id: 4 },
                    { text: 'Thu', id: 5 },
                    { text: 'Fri', id: 6 },
                    { text: 'Sat', id: 7 }
                ];
            },
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: "/flat-ui/tpls/weekly-scheduler.html",
        };
    })
```

where is my directive template

```
<ul style="padding: 0px;display: inline;margin: 0;list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="weekDay in weekDays" style="padding: 10px;display: inline;">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{weekDay.id}}" check-list="data.weeklyDetails" id="{{'chk_'+$index}}" class="ee-check"> <label class="ee-check" for="{{'chk_'+$index}}"><span></span> {{weekDay.text}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my weekly directive, I have used another directive which handles my checkbox list

```
.directive('checkList', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                list: '=checkList',
                value: '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                var handler = function(setup) {
                    var checked = elem.prop('checked');
                    var index = scope.list.indexOf(scope.value);
                    if (checked && index == -1) {
                        if (setup) elem.prop('checked', false);
                        else scope.list.push(scope.value);
                    } else if (!checked && index != -1) {
                        if (setup) elem.prop('checked', true);
                        else scope.list.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                };

                var setupHandler = handler.bind(null, true);
                var changeHandler = handler.bind(null, false);

                elem.bind('change', function() {
                    scope.$apply(changeHandler);
                });
                scope.$watch('list', setupHandler, true);
            }
        };
    });
```

now I am trying to write test cases to test my directive

```
describe("weeklyDirective directive", function() {
    var elm, scope, httpBackend, controller;
    beforeEach(module('guideApp.directives'));
    beforeEach(module('/flat-ui/tpls/weekly-scheduler.html'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        compile = $compile;
        scope = $rootScope;
        elm = angular.element('<div weekly-directive data="data"></div>');
        compile(elm)(scope);
        scope.data = {
            interval: 1,
            weeklyDetails: ['1'],
        }
        scope.$digest();
    }));
    it("click on check box it should get added in weeklyDetails", function() {
        var e = elm.find('input[id="chk_3"]');
        console.log(e);
        e.trigger('click');
        scope.$apply();
        var isolateScope = elm.isolateScope();
        expect(isolateScope.data.weeklyDetails.indexOf('4') > -1).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

where I am trying to test that when user click on check box its value should get added to my array **weeklyDetails** which in data object (passed to the weeklydirective).

its not working as exptected for me please help me to get this working.
Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Click event not working ah?

Comment: Yes that should be handled by the checkList directive and add the checked element into array.

Comment: I would advise moving your logic from the link function to a separate controller. Also, isolateScope() was removed in Angular 1.2 (?)